# Force run of BucketDeployment with cdk when the source have changed

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cdk

In cdk/python, I have this piece of code to basically read a zip on a S3 bucket and to extract it on another bucket:

```py
deployment = aws_s3_deployment.BucketDeployment(
    self,
    "UploadFrontendFromMainBucket",
    sources=[
        aws_s3_deployment.Source.bucket(
            src_bucket,
            zip_object_key="dist.zip",
        )
    ],
    destination_bucket=dest_bucket,
    destination_key_prefix="/",
    extract=True,
    retain_on_delete=self._deployto != "tst",
    prune=False,
)
deployment.node.add_dependency(api, dest_bucket)
```

This works perfectly *the first time*.

If the source file (dist.zip) changes or the target bucket is emptied, running the stack again will not deploy again. There is no extra parameter to the `Source.bucket` construct. The `Source.assets` has a hash parameter, but I would rather not have to download the source zip first to compute a hash

How can I force another deployment if the source zip file has changed?

Comment: You would have to change some prop of the construct to force it to update. Changing the construct ID is a sure way, but be aware that this will trigger the creating of a new custom resource, and afterwards the deletion of the original one, which can delete the newly deployed files. (set retain_on_delete to true in this case)